# Program lists all primes between 0 and n, but also includes 4, 6, and 8

Tags: java

This is my code.

```
public class PrimeNumbers
{

private int upperLimit;

public PrimeNumbers()
{

}

public boolean isPrime(int c)
{
    boolean x = true;
    for(int i = 3; i < (int)(Math.sqrt(c)) + 1; i++)
    {
        if(c % i == 0)
        {
            x = false;
        }
        if(c % 2 == 0)
        {
            x = false;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

public void countPrimes(int upperLimit)
{
    this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
    int counter = 0;
    System.out.println("The prime numbers between 1 and " + this.upperLimit + " are:");
    for(int n = 1; n < this.upperLimit; n++)
    {
        if(isPrime(n))
        {
            System.out.println(n);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The amount of prime numbers between 1 and " + this.upperLimit + " is: " + counter);
} 
 }
```

Here is my Tester Class.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class PrimeNumbersTester
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    PrimeNumbers a = new PrimeNumbers();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the upper limit.");
    int upperLimit = in.nextInt();
    a.countPrimes(upperLimit);
}
}
```

I tested this program using 1000. It seems to list all of the prime numbers in the range, but it also lists 4, 6, and 8, which are not prime numbers. I am unsure what is causing this.

Comment: Why do you have a special `if (c % 2 == 0)` bit in your `isPrime` rather than just starting with `i = 2`? (Think about how often that loop is currently being executed when `c` is less than 9...)

Comment: once you have determined the number is not prime, why do you keep checking more numbers?

Comment: It works if I change that, thanks. I'm not quite sure why I had that now that I look back on it.

Comment: First of all, [1 is not a prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number), so `n` should start at `2`. On the other hand, `4, 6, 8` are printed because you start checking primality with `3` instead of `2`.

Answer (score 0):

The function should be look like this I thing this will work :

```
public boolean isPrime(int c)
  {
      boolean x = true;
      int j;
      for (j=2; j<c;j++)
        {
            if(c%j==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(c==j)
        {
            return true;
        }
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: It is not necessary to reach `c`. Is enough with `sqrt(c) + 1`. It's call [Trial division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division)

Comment: @Albert Yes I agree Albert, but for this small logic why we involve any math function. I have assumed that the code should be simple to understand for any beginner.